# How to identlfy if the HTML element has AngularJS behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I have a browser where I need to identify whether the clicked element has AngularJS component or not. Is there a way to identify it?

Comment: _I need to identify whether the clicked element_ how you are clicking on it, do you have that piece of code?

Comment: $(this) will give me the HTML element

Answer (score 1):

You cant be 100% sure if the element has AngularJS behavior but you could do one of the following:

- check if angularjs is loadet at all (check `window.angular`)
- check if there is a angualrjs class on one of the parent elements like `ng-scope`
- check if there is any AngularJS directive on the element (like `ng-click`)

Answer (score 0):

You can identify by checking if the clicked element has an `ng-click` directive for example (but it's not necessary) or an `ng-app` on the `<body>`.

Comment: ng-app on the body doesn't mean there cant be other normal HTML elements right?

Comment: ng-click is not mandatory. Smiliarly any other ng-<attribute> is not mandatory.